# Is Sam Tarly the only person in the current age to have killed a White Walker?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Sam Tarly, a brother of the Night’s Watch, bravely stabbed a White Walker to protect Gilly and her "little monster" (unnamed in the books, if I recall).  Sam's weapon of choice was a dragonglass dagger given to him by Jon Snow from a cache of weapons north of the Wall.

Since the Battle of Dawn, has no one else encountered a White Walker and survived?  Has no other character been given the opportunity to try a dragonglass or Valyrian steel weapon?

I use only the books tag, I know in the show Lord Snow killed two (one at Hardhome and one in the wight hunting expedition) and Meera killed one with a dragonglass spear in the Three-Eye Raven cave.

Comment: Calling the dagger Sam's "weapon of choice" is a bit much. :P

Comment: Sam should roll up on House Tarly and yell "I've killed a g-damn White Walker, give me the damn ancestral sword and my frreakin' seat of inheritance back, DIckon!" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

In fact the Others haven’t been seen in centuries, the first time they resurface is in the prologue of *A Game of Thrones* and even then Gared is seen as a mad man rather than taken seriously.

Most people in Westeros don’t believe they ever existed and they are placed into the same sort of category as grumpkins.

> Unique in the Seven Kingdoms is the Night's Watch, the sworn brotherhood that has defended the Wall over centuries and millennia, born in the aftermath of the Long Night, the generation-long winter that brought the Others down on the realms of men and nearly put an end to them.
>
> The history of the Night's Watch is a long one. Tales still tell of the black knights of the Wall and their noble calling. But the Age of Heroes is long done, and the Others have not shown themselves in thousands of years, if indeed they ever existed.
>
> <sub>*The World of Ice and Fire, The Wall and Beyond: The Night’s Watch*</sub>

Comment: Great answer, thank you!  With the upcoming series final season, I tried to compare where the books had left off.  Rumor is the next book is nearly done and may see publication within a year, so who know what we may see there...

Comment: @m1gp0z that rumour has been the same for a few years as in “it’ll be done next year” I wouldn’t hold out hope.

Comment: "But this time, it's really, really true" :-) I know, dreams of a sweet summer child

Comment: "brought the Others down on the realms of men and nearly put an end to them" - how? They can't get around the wall, so it seems boats are out. So Essos seems safe in any event.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz We're talking about Westeros here not Essos and that quote is talking about The Long Night which happened before the Wall was constructed. We also don't know for sure if they can or can't cross at the sea.

Comment: "The Long Night which happened before the Wall was constructed" - sure, but if they could swim or take boats, there would be no point in building the wall. Yet they built it.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz And if you mean how can they bring an end to men if they can't get to Essos well the two used to be connected at one point. And TWOIAF is very Westerosi centred at certain places so it makes sense to ignore that. And we know very little about them. The Wall may well be just good enough as a deterrent rather than an actual defence but it does contain magic so that could answer it too.